# updating radicale (CalDAV server) in Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, caldav

I run a number of Linux servers in windows desktop environments. On a couple of them (one at work, one at home) I run radicale CalDAV servers for the benefit of iPhone users. These servers all get periodically updated along the Fedora release path as well as with frequent package updates.

With regards to CalDAV, I had a couple of issues I wanted to work on:
1) I was unhappy that all of my calendars were named caldav"on the phones,
   due to the file tree being set up as collections/username/caldav
   I had hoped to just rename the file tree to be collections/caldav/username
   I figured that since I did not use actual authentication, I could just
   rotate the files and rotate the URL correspondingly. That caused everything
   to stop working.
2) I also upgraded one of the servers from F26 to F27.

Since then, nothing has worked.

After some sleuthing, I find that
   F26 -> python 2.7.14 *and* python3 3.6.4 -           radicale 1.1.6
   F27 -> python 2.7.14 *and* python3 3.6.4 -           radicale 2.1.8

The documentation says the file tree structure has changes from radicale 1.x to radicale 2.x and one needs to do a conversion by exporting from the old file tree into an empty folder before the upgrade.

So it looks like I am in some amount of trouble.

Any ideas for how to clean up my mess?

Who on Superuser has done work with radicale in a Red Hat environment and survived the 1.x -> 2.x upgrade?

Comment: My first idea (and generally the preferred method) would include grabbing the last pre-upgrade (radicale) and export that to some file on the system and then backup what you have on the present setup (to grab any delta since) and then nuke the new directory and import the exported backup to that re-created directory and then resolve any delta once it's sane again.